# Modify existing object values

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm starting to lose my mind and need some help.
I have a function as following:

```
private generateTimeObject(firstObject: someInterface, secondObject?: someInterface) {
  let firstTime;
  let secondTime;

  if (condition) {
    firstTime = firstObject.time;
    secondTime = secondObject ? secondObject.time : null;
  } else {
    firstTime = firstObject.someOtherTimeValue;
    secondTime = secondObject ? secondObject.someOtherTimeValue : null;
  }

   firstObject.customValues = {
    firstTimeValue: firstTime,
    secondTimeValue: secondTime
  };
}
```

Now, following scenario:

The function gets called like this: generateTimeObject(firstObject).
This means, the function creates a subObject customValues as follow:

```
firstObject.customValues = {firstTimeValue, null}
```

Now, this function gets called again. This time like this: generateTimeObject(firstObject, secondObject).

The function now is supposed to write the firstObject as follow

```
firstObject.customValues = {firstTimeValue, secondTimeValue}
```

However, i can't get this to work. The secondTimeValue remains null, and i really can't figure out why. I've also tried using Object.assign() already, but it still didn't work.

Any help in figuring this out, will be really appreciated.

Here's a jsFiddle. Sadly, it seems to work fine, so my problem must lie elsewhere. I'm assuming it has something to do with reference or scope, but i just can't figure it out.
https://jsfiddle.net/pna75vrd/6/

Comment: Please supply a [mcve]. Right now your code doesn't demonstrate the problem and all we can do is attempt to guess what it might even be.

Comment: Right, i have made a jsFiddle, and sadly it seems to work as expected. So maybe my problem lies elsewhere. Still, here:
https://jsfiddle.net/pna75vrd/5/

Comment: It is better if you can recreate the problem with code here on Stack Overflow. You can likely use a Stack Snippet (`<>` on the toolbar), which has an interface much like JSFiddle's. You'll need to use JavaScript rather than TypeScript.

Comment: Why your function doesn't have a `reurn` ?  The jsfiddle code is not enough to tell what's happening on your real case.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @foxiris Because i don't actually need to return anything. The function extends an existing object (that i pass to the function)

Answer (score -1):

In this type of situation my next step to resolve this problem would be to attach a debugger and step through the code, or simply add some console.log() statements to output the values of the variables so that you can interrogate what they are, and how they differ from what you're expecting. For example:

```
private generateTimeObject(firstObject: someInterface, secondObject?: someInterface) {
  let firstTime;
  let secondTime;
  
  console.log("firstObject=", firstObject)
  console.log("secondObject=", secondObject)

  if (condition) {
    console.log("condition==true")
    firstTime = firstObject.time;
    secondTime = secondObject ? secondObject.time : null;
  } else {
    console.log("condition==false")
    firstTime = firstObject.someOtherTimeValue;
    secondTime = secondObject ? secondObject.someOtherTimeValue : null;
  }
  
  console.log("firstTime=", firstTime)
  console.log("secondTime=", secondTime)

  firstObject.customValues = {
    firstTimeValue: firstTime,
    secondTimeValue: secondTime
  };
  
  console.log("Again, firstObject=", firstObject)
}
```

Off the top of my head, it might be that when the function is called for the second time, either `secondObject.time` or `secondObject.someOtherTimeValue` is null.

Comment: Hi William

I removed the console.logs to make the code shorter. I'm working with console.logs and can see that the values i'm trying to set do indeed exist. I just can't figure out for the life of me why i can't overwrite them. In the jsFiddle it seems to work, but in my actual code it does not. I can just imagine this has something to do with reference and scope, but i don't know what it is.